# Image quality losses when a image embed to wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, image

Hi I'm creating a wordpress website. When i added a image to wordpress page, its quality totally lost. its look like blurred image. The image was created in photoshop with size 
870x300 Px, Image quality- 100% and it was in JPEG format.

Please tell me what to do to get quality back.

Comment: check for the size of image you are fetching when you display your post/page

Comment: @Ashish thanks man! :), That was the problem. as default it was medium size 300X219. When i added into the page in admin panel its appear in small size so i try to adjust size by adding exact width and height in html tags that y its appeared blurred in webpage !. Thank you once again :).

Comment: Hmm It's wordpress a lots of things are there

Comment: Also i'am looking for neat image slider plugin for my wordpress website. Can you suggest me one

Comment: soliloquy slider is good one but there are others too google them and you will find

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is due to a misconfiguration. Check your image settings in your Wordpress "Settings > Media" section.

And by the way take a look at this article:
http://www.woothemes.com/2014/01/wordpress-image-compression/

Tell me if I can be of further assistance.

Sincere regards,
Eduardo Macho